# Where does VSCODE sync setting feature saves users' setting data?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I went going through the following article and I learned about the built-in sync setting feature:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

I am not able to find where exactly VSCODE stores my sync data.

Where does VSCODE sync setting feature saves users' setting data?

Answer (score 3):

From console output, we can see that sync service is located right there:
https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/

```
2023-05-02 14:29:07.535 [info] Using settings sync service https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/
```

Comment: URL is also indicated in VS Code documentation here : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#:~:text=trafficmanager.net%20%2D-,Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Settings%20Sync%20service,-vscode%2Dsync%2Dinsiders

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync), it says:

*Selecting the Sign in & Turn on button will ask you to choose between signing in with your **Microsoft** or **GitHub** account.*

If you are talking about **where it saves in cloud**, there's no information about that. Remember that vs code it's owned by Microsoft, [here's the vscode repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode). Couldn't find anything concretely helpful, but i'm sure they have their own databases for this services.